# What is the alternative to structs in perl?

Tags: perl

Perl doesn't have the concept of struct by default. We need to Import Struct Class. I was wondering why is this so? and What combination of basic data structures provided by the language is supposed to compensate for this?

Comment: Why? Because we perl user prefer using modules. This is no different from C++ user use boost, Visual C user use MFC, etc..

Answer (score 14):

Hashes do pretty much the same thing in Perl as structs do in C (in terms of what you use them for). You can also [nest hashes](http://p3rl.org/dsc) to build more complex data structures.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I went though the doc you provided. But it doesnt look as intuitive as I would like especially considering maintainability . Considering committing the unholy sin of moving to a different language midway though a project. python seems to be the balance at this point

Answer (score 5):

If you have existing C header files with structs, use [Convert::Binary::C](http://p3rl.org/Convert%3a%3aBinary%3a%3aC) to access data structures based on them.

Answer (score 3):

Class::Struct never fit the role of C structs for me. In my mind, a C struct is a known memory structure that organizes data, but it's best use for me was always the automatic parsing of fixed length input records into fields just by writing them to the struct.

You can do something similar with unpack. It still requires a separate parsing call C doesn't, but if you build it into your record read, it's pretty efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this module as an alternative to structs - [Class::Struct](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.16.0/lib/Class/Struct.pm)

Comment: If we're substituting classes for structs, then we might as well use [Moose](http://moose.perl.org) instead; it has much more advanced capabilities, especially for parameter validation.